# convert integers to doubles to make program calculate average of number of tests

Tags: c, type-conversion

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        int numgrades;
        double numdob;
        int grade;
        double avg;
        int sum;
        int i=0;
        scanf("%d",&numgrades);
        for(i=0;i<numgrades;i++){
            scanf("%d\n",&grade);
            sum=sum+grade;
        }
        numdob = (double)numgrades;
        avg=sum/numdob;
        printf("%.2lf",avg);
        return 0;
    }
```

For this code I get the warning:

```
787490190680209271.c:15:12: warning: ‘sum’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     avg=sum/numdob;
            ^
```

I cant find what wrong. This is a simple program that get firs input of number of tests and then grades to those tests one by one. Output should be the average of the grades.

Comment: `int sum;` ==> `int sum = 0;` ... that was a very helpful tip from your compiler! With a little bit of experience you will learn to understand compiler diagnostics better, But, basically, read them and think what the compiler wanted to say is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

o.k the only thing that was missing is to assign value 0 when i declared the int sum.